# Anyone try running SharePoint Designer on a Mac using virtual machine software (VMWare, Oracle Virtual Box, etc)?

Tags: designer, oracle, mac-os-x, vmware

What's the experience and performance like if so and what is your Mac setup?

I've switched from a Mac to a Surface Pro (fully loaded) with two 4k monitors and I'm surprised how clunky/sluggish this system feels compared to my fully loaded 2012 MacBook Pro. I also really miss OS X in general and all the keyboard shortcuts and everything. The only reason I switched at work is because I have to use SharePoint designer so I needed a PC.

While I was waiting for my Surface to arrive, I had a PC desktop and my MacBook Pro and I was using Synergy to share my keyboard/mouse between the PC and Mac which worked alright. I'm almost contemplating getting rid of my surface and going back to that but wanted to see if there were maybe some other options with virtualization out there?

So, any Mac Sharepoint Developers out there? What's your setup?

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot of it depends on what do you use SharePoint Designer for? If you are using it for branding, you can complete most branding tasks outside of SharePoint Designer if you are SharePoint 2013+. The ability to add a mapped network drive really opens up your branding tasks on a Mac with no SPD.

Next thing is what is your SharePoint site access like? I used to run Parallels and that type of thing but now I just remote to the SharePoint web server when I need to use SharePoint Designer or IE. Through Microsoft Remote Desktop you can connect to the SP web server and use all of the tools there.

If that isn't an option for you, you can try out a tool like VirtualBox or Crossover Mac.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, Heather. I'm having trouble finding information about SharePoint web server and Microsoft Remote Desktop? Do you have any resources?

Also, how's the performance of using SharePoint Designer through Remote Desktop on a Mac?

Comment: Resources (2 links): https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop-10/id1295203466?mt=12


https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-mac


The performance is fine. If you run into issues just lower the color for the connection. For example, I use True Color (24 bit) as opposed to Highest Quality (32 bit) and I don't experience any lag. A lot of it depends on your host machine.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for those resources. Exactly what I was looking for.